# java.lang.stackoverflow error

Tags: android, viewflipper, stack-overflow

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
 <ViewFlipper 
  android:id="@+id/vf1"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">    
   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/a1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/left1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/left64"/>
     <Button
        android:id="@+id/left2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/left128"/>
 <RadioGroup
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
     <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio12"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="set0"
        android:text="Select"/>
 <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio11"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="set0"
        android:text="Select" />
     </RadioGroup>
   </RelativeLayout>
.
.
N more relative layouts like this then

 </ViewFlipper>
</RelativeLayout>
```

when N<=3 it works fine, BUT when N>3 java.lang.stackoverflow error come directly while parsing the xml file while switching to graphical layout. I am building it on API 17. I've read in many blogs that this error occurs because of very deep hierarchy of layouts, but I don't think my hierarchy is too deep. Is it? Also is there any way to increase stack size in android? Pls provide me its solution if any1 finds it out

Comment: You could remove the outer RL which would remove at least one level...

Comment: `while parsing the xml file while switching to graphical layout` Do you also have an error on the device? If not, and you only need graphical layout editing, try DroidDraw. Also, @WarrenFaith's suggestion should help.

Comment: i wanted to put 1 button & 1 viewflipper in outer RL so I added it.

Comment: got rid of this problem by using imageview instead of buttons....sounds strange but true...if any of u know the reason please share it